# How to parse microseconds that are not zero padded?

Tags: python, datetime

I am parsing log files which have timestamps in the following format:

```
At 162210 usecs after Fri Aug 23 19:46:00 2019
```

To convert this into a datetime object, I have been doing the following:

```
ts = datetime.strptime(ts_raw, "At %f usecs after %a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
```

This seemed to be working great until I ran into a timestamp like:

```
At 75127 usecs after Fri Aug 23 19:44:55 2019
```

`strptime()` treats the 75127 as the fractional portion of a decimal and thus the resulting object is `19:44:55.751270` instead of the hoped-for `19:44:55.075127`.

To work around this I am using a regex to parse the microseconds separately and then modify the datetime object:

```
res = re.search("At (\d+) usecs after (.*)", ts_raw)
if res != None:
    usec = res.group(1)
    ts_raw = res.group(2)
    ts = datetime.strptime(ts_raw, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
    ts = ts.replace(microsecond=int(usec))
```

This correctly parses the string into the expected datetime object, but it  seems rather clunky and inelegant.  Is there a cleaner way to achieve this?

I was hoping the `%f` format specifier might have some modifiers that could be used to achieve this but I was unable to find anything like that.

Comment: the duplicate confirms that you need to pre/post process your microseconds. I would preprocess to add a 0 if "At xxxxx" hasn't enough digits, your solution also works

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Sorry about the dup - I did search before posting - honest!

Comment: TBH I saw this issue before. I googled "python datetime parse microseconds". But I have a gold badge and you haven't. So you're forgiven :)